# An unpublished paper of Thurston about diffeomorphism groups

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, differential-topology

William Thurston has done many contributions in the field of diffeomorphism groups. But it seems that one of his papers entitled

"On the Structure of the Group of Volume Preserving Diffeomorphisms"

was never published. I want to know if any digital copy of this paper is available somewhere?

Comment: Are you sure it was even written?